In Swift, can underlying type of a publicly returned opaque type be internal?
It's understandable if the answer is no. But if yes, please tell how that works.
I am asking because the following code does not give compile time errors:
// This is an internal type.
struct InternalType: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String = "Hi, there"
    var value: Int
}

// This function is public and returns an opaque type.
public func createOpaqueType() -> some CustomStringConvertible {
    return InternalType(value: 42)
}

As far as outside is concerned, it can use the return only as a CustomStringConvertible. But does not the compiler needs to have access to the underlying type?

Yes, the compiler needs to have access to the underlying type to enforce type safety and check conformance to the protocols. However, this does not mean that the underlying type must be publicly visible; it can remain internal. The opaque type mechanism allows the compiler to know and verify the underlying type without exposing it to the outside world.
